# Access ipv6 addresses via ipv4 vpn

Tags: vpn, linux-networking

Here is my VPN configuration. My vpc which is in the cloud only support IPv4 and it have public IPv4 address. Client machines have both IPv6 and IPv4 public addresses. When I try to access to internet client machine always route with IPv6 and not go through VPN. If I disable IPv6 in client machine then it all routes to VPN. Is there any way to resolve this without explicitly disabling IPv6 on client machines.

Comment: It is 2019, so make you VPN server speak IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to resolve this without explicitly disabling IPv6 on client machines

It depends on what you mean by resolve. You can edit /etc/gai/conf to [prefer IPv4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32298/prefer-a-ipv4-dns-lookups-before-aaaaipv6-lookups). if IPv6 is enabled on the client it can though, still be used. You may still be better off disabling it (you can do it on the fly using sysctl commands) or block it using your firewall. Either (or both) could be added to an OpenVPN connect/disconnect script.